# Scope of server callback in aura action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura

Aura Action javascript object has setCallback function that we use to communicate with the server. The first parameter of the function is scope. Aura documentation has the following explanation:

> **Scope** : Object
>
> The scope in which the function is executed. You almost always want to set scope to the keyword this.

Experimenting with *this* keyword inside the component results in *undefined* when used inside controller.js and the helper object instance when used inside helper.js. Does someone know what the scope parameter is affecting? Using *this* feels wrong as it can be almost anything depending on the place in code the setCallback is executed from.

P.S. currently I have problems with private attribute visibility inside the action callback function so I am trying to eliminate all possible causes.

Comment: Yea you probably want setCallback(component, function(){});

Comment: Can you post some info and source code relating to your private attribute visibility issue?

Comment: I would post the issue with the private attribute in a separate post if I don't find a solution. I still need to experiment with it to eliminate all external factors. However, I would still like to know how scope affects the execution of the aura action. Why do you suggest to set the scope to component?

Comment: What else would you want it set to? Ideally you get passed in everything you need, so you shouldn't need to set it to anything in particular.

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't help me understanding how setting the scope affects the execution of the server callout.

Comment: It only effects the this context of the client side callback. Nothing on the server is influenced.

Comment: By server callout I meant the whole javascript setCallback invocation, not the processing on the server.

Comment: Right. So that first parameter just influences what is in the "this" context for your callback function. Are you having an access check issue?

Comment: Ok thanks I understand now. Doesn't sound as a very useful property thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @KrisGray pointed out in the comments - the scope affects *this* attribute inside the callback function.