# Lightning Components: What is the meaning and purpose of the scope parameter of Action.prototype.setCallback()?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

Typically we use `setCallback()` to invoke apex methods from components like so

```
var call1 = cmp.get("c.myServerSideAction_1");
call1.setCallback(this,function(res)) {
    if(res.getState()=='SUCCESS') {
          // ... some logic here
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(call1);
```

The documentation in the Aura Sourcecode suggests to use `this` as `scope`.

Now in the context of a different question I found that I'm passing in most cases `null` instead of `this` because I moved all invocations to a static resource where I have no meaningful `this` context to feed into `setCallback()`.

Unfortunately I can't figure what the meaning and reason for this super strange `scope` parameter is at all. It feels just useless and as an obstacle to me and I passed `null` out of frustration. Surprisingly it worked with no difference. Now in the context of a differnt question here [Lightning Components: why are subsequent invocations of $A.enqueueAction() so super SLOW?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189367/lightning-components-why-are-subsequent-invocations-of-a-enqueueaction-so-su)   about nested apex invocations I have performance issues and @CasparHarmer guessed the `scope` parameter could have an impact on performance.

I would like to understand `scope`

Can anyone point me to where I can read more about this `scope` or explain to me it's purpose? I can't find more background information on it.

This question is similar to this  [Scope of server callback in aura action](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150701)  but has actually received a better and more detailed answer.

Comment: This is about as good as I could find: In non-strict mode, `this` cannot be `null`, so it's replaced with the global object instead. Try setting your javascript to strict and see what you get.

Comment: In fact, if it's not replaced by a Locker Service Secure version, then you'll have escalated yourself outside of the Lightning sandbox and may have exposed a bug

Comment: could this be related [Scope of server callback in aura action](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150701/scope-of-server-callback-in-aura-action) ?

Comment: @CasparHarmer I'm in a v36 compo, so no LockerService or at least not the angry version of it...

Comment: @glls I think that is it exactly! Thanks! If I got it right, then if I dont't use `this` in my callbak at all, `scope` does not make any difference at all, correct? This is so irritating and there should be a scopeless version of setCallback() especially because `this` is different in controllers and helper and people move code around between the two of them...

Comment: What I'm saying is that by passing in `null`, scope is elevated to global scope. It'll still work, but you'll probably have access to stuff you normally wouldn't have.

Comment: cool, I might have hacked the LockerService ;-) yippee! it never was my best friend...

Comment: Maybe helpful. I asked a question that turns out to be similar: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159399/what-is-this-pattern-for-self-this. Nuts, I see you have an answer. Regardless leaving comment in case it does have useful information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `scope` parameter used by the callback is supposed to provide your helper context to the callback so that you can continue to have access to other helper functions (which are available via the `this` scope in the helper). The framework does this by invoking your callback using [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and passing your `scope` as the `this` argument. For why this is important consider the following:

```
function main() {
    console.log('Main');
    this.other();
    try {
        this.secret();
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log('Secret unavailable!');
    }
}

function other() {
    console.log('Other');
}

function secret() {
    console.log('You found a secret.');
}

// Call main with the top-level "this"
console.log('-- Calling Window version --');
main();

var scope = {
    other: function() {
        console.log('Scoped Other');
    }
};

// Call the main and pass a custom scope
console.log('-- Calling scoped version --');
main.call(scope);
```

This will print out:

```
-- Calling Window version --
Main
Other 
You found a secret.
-- Calling scoped version -- 
Main 
Scoped Other 
Secret unavailable!
```

As you can see here, using `call` to invoke a function provides an important level of encapsulation for the framework. When you pass `this` to your callback you are propagating your helper state down to the callback. I am not sure exactly what the use case is but you could pass a different object there if you wanted your callback to have access to a different scope.